# Azure / U-SQL - output query to screen

Tags: sql, visual-studio, azure, u-sql

I'm new to U-SQL in Azure (I'm pretty familiar with SQL Server) and can't figure out how to see the output of a query.

All the example's I'm able to find involve writing the results to a file via an outputter.

Do I need to push everything to a table for viewing in `Data Explorer` or is there a way to get the output to a results window like in `SSMS`?

Note - I'm using the free version of Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest looking at Hive and Visual Studio Code for an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, interactive queries are not available.  You will need to output the results to a file and then review that file.